# Can PayPal invoicing be used after a PayPal Transaction have been made?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have a web site that is using PayPal for digital goods (express checkout) to charge customers.

I am obliged by IRC to send my customer an invoice after a transaction have been made.

My Question is: 
Can PayPal invoicing be used after a PayPal Transaction have been made (and not as a charging method)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal invoice cannot be used as a receipt for orders. What you could do is when customers checkout, set up a redirect page inside your PayPal account. On that page, have PHP that emails customers a summary of their order.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has tools to do that, however it requires coding which you probably would want a developer for. PayPal has what is called Instant Payment Notifications (IPN's) that you can have Paypal turn on and you can put in your website code.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/